# Subquery not allowed in this context

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I'm trying to check if the `LEDGER_CODE` exists in the table `MIGRATED_TYPES`. When checking the `LEDGER_CODE` like the code below, I received the error message.

> Subquery not allowed in this context.

```
BEGIN
    IF :LEDGER.CODE IN (SELECT CODE FROM MIGRATED_TYPES) THEN
        Message('This type has been disabled.');
        RAISE form_trigger_failure;
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a variable to get the code as  `SELECT CODE into v_code FROM MIGRATED_TYPES`
And then use it within if as

```
If :ledger.code in (v_code)
```

You cannot use a subquery directly within if.